# Can I view a colleague's calendar over API for Google Calendar for business? Want to use this for detecting possible times to schedule meetings

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I can see their calendars on the web when I sign on, can I retrieve this from API? I hope to be able to build an intelligent meeting assistant.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/) docs right now:

> The Google Data Calendar Resource API is now **deprecated** and is scheduled for sunset in January 2017. Apps should instead use the **Directory API**'s Calendar Resource object.

As for the suggested [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/), I think you could specifically use the [resources.calendars.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/get) which is described in the docs as (with parameters):

> Retrieves a calendar resource.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - **calendarResourceId** - The unique ID of the calendar resource to retrieve.
> - **customer** - The **unique ID for the customer's Google account**. As an account administrator, you can also use the my_customer alias to represent your account's customer ID.

-- where I think you can specify the user to get that specific calendar from.